# gdb break condition in++

Tags: c++, gdb

i download chromium and build it by

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Install-additional-build-dependencies

then i start it with gdb

```
gdb out/Default/chrome
```

i want set breakpoints when the url contains [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com),

```
break SimpleURLLoaderImpl::StartRequest
condtion (int)resource_request_->url.spec().find("www.googleapis.com",0) > 0
```

ant got the error

```
An error occurred while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(std::__Cr::unique_ptr<network::ResourceRequest, std::__Cr::default_delete<network::ResourceRequest> >::o
perator->() const) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

Comment: Does it work if you try `print (int)resource_request_->url.spec().find("www.googleapis.com",0)` on the breakpoint?

Comment: @ssbssa yes, it works, and i figure out it `break SimpleURLLoaderImpl::Start
  condition $bpnum $_regex((char *)resource_request_.__ptr_->__value_->url , "https://(accounts.google.com|www.googleapis.com).*")`